Implement the user update feature on React PWA
I want to implement a user-clicked app update feature of a React PWA. I want to show a Chakra-UI toast which has a button, on whose click the PWA updates.
This is my service worker file code so far
// import { env } from 'env';

import { clientsClaim, RouteMatchCallback } from 'workbox-core';
import { createHandlerBoundToURL, precacheAndRoute } from 'workbox-precaching';
import { NavigationRoute, registerRoute } from 'workbox-routing';
import { NetworkOnly } from 'workbox-strategies';
import { Workbox } from 'workbox-window';

import { serverEndpoints } from '../api/endpoints';

import { platform } from './platformDetection';
import {
  APPLICATION_JSON,
  AUTHORIZATION,
  CONTENT_TYPE,
  DB,
  ErrCodes,
  deviceId,
  SwMessageType,
} from './swConstants';
import {
  factory,
  getBody,
  initToken,
  json,
  logger,
  routeMatcher,
  updateRequest,
} from './swUtils';

declare const self: ServiceWorkerGlobalScope;

// Connection to a broadcast channel
const bc = new BroadcastChannel('token_updates');

/** Buffer time between access token requests (4sec) */
const buffer = 4000 as const;

/**
 * Access token timeout duration.
 *
 * Value is set as the app configuration api response (`access_token_expiry_in_seconds`)
 *
 * @defaultValue 15min
 */
let accessTokenTimeout = 15 * 60 * 1000 - buffer;

/**
 * The id of setTimeout of access token.
 * This is used to detect if there's a current timeout set for access token
 */
let timerId: NodeJS.Timer | undefined;

let isInitCalled = false;
/**
 * Listens for the 'fetch' event and calls the `init()` function if it has not been called yet.
 * This ensures that the service worker is properly initialized before handling any fetch requests.
 */
self.addEventListener('fetch', () => {
  if (!isInitCalled) init();
});

const accessToken = initToken();
const refreshToken = initToken();
const subscription = initToken(); // initializing subscription token
clientsClaim();
self.skipWaiting();

precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST);

// initial setup for new worker
self.addEventListener('activate', init);

// Set up App Shell-style routing, so that all navigation requests
// are fulfilled with your index.html shell.
// https://developer.chrome.com/docs/workbox/modules/workbox-routing/#how-to-register-a-navigation-route
registerRoute(
  new NavigationRoute(createHandlerBoundToURL('/index.html'), {
    denylist: [/\/docs*/],
  })
);

self.addEventListener('install', self.skipWaiting);

self.addEventListener('message', async (event) => {
  const data = event.data;
  if (!data) return;

  switch (data.type as SwMessageType) {
    case 'SKIP_WAITING':
      self.skipWaiting();
      break;
    case 'fetchaccesstoken':
      fetchAccessToken();
      break;
    default:
      try {
        await refreshToken;
        await accessToken;
      } catch (e) {
        logger.error('default postMessage', e);
      }
  }
});

/** Local Login */
registerRoute(
  routeMatcher('/login', location.origin),
  factory(async () =>
    json({
      is_logged_in: Boolean(await refreshToken.catch(() => false)),
    })
  )
);

/** Local logout */
registerRoute(
  routeMatcher('/logout', location.origin),
  factory(async () => {
    fetch(serverEndpoints.logout, {
      headers: [[AUTHORIZATION, `Bearer ${await accessToken.catch(() => '')}`]],
      method: 'PUT',
    });
    storeOrDeleteRefreshToken(true);
    accessToken.update(Promise.reject(ErrCodes.LOGIN_REQUIRED));
    refreshToken.update(Promise.reject(ErrCodes.LOGIN_REQUIRED));

    return json({ message: 'logged out' });
  })
);

// this route is specifically for ios but also can be used for android
registerRoute(
  routeMatcher('/subscribe', location.origin),
  factory(async (request) => {
    const req = await request.json();
    const existingSub = await self.registration.pushManager.getSubscription();
    try {
      if (existingSub) {
        subscription.update(Promise.resolve(existingSub.toString()));
        return json(existingSub);
      }
      const sub = await self.registration.pushManager.subscribe({
        userVisibleOnly: true,
        applicationServerKey: req.vapid,
      });
      console.log('ios sub : ', sub);
      subscription.update(Promise.resolve(sub.toString()));
      return json(sub);
    } catch (e: any) {
      return new Response(JSON.stringify({ message: e.message }), {
        status: 500,
        headers: { [CONTENT_TYPE]: APPLICATION_JSON },
      });
    }
  }),
  'POST'
);

// Local refresh route for refreshing the access token and send push notification token to server
// we are passing stringified Push Subscription or fcm token in the device_id field
registerRoute(
  routeMatcher('/refresh', location.origin),
  factory(async (request) => {
    let req = await request.json();
    subscription.update(Promise.resolve(req.device_id));
    let Body;
    if (platform == 'ios') {
      Body = JSON.stringify({ os: platform, device_id: req.device_id });
    } else {
      Body = JSON.stringify({ os: platform, device_id: req.device_id });
    }

    const res = await fetch(serverEndpoints.access_token, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: Body,
      headers: new Headers([
        [AUTHORIZATION, `Bearer ${await refreshToken}`],
        [CONTENT_TYPE, APPLICATION_JSON],
      ]),
    });
    return res;
  }),
  'POST'
);

//  Event listener for push notifications
self.addEventListener('push', async (event) => {
  console.log('1pushevent', event);
  const data = await event?.data?.json();
  console.log('noteventdata', data);
  let notificationTitle = data?.notification?.title || 'New Message Received';
  let notificationBody = data?.notification?.body || '';
  let notificationIcon = data?.notification?.image || '';
  let notificationData = data?.data || {};
  console.log('platform', platform);
  if (platform === 'ios') {
    notificationTitle = data?.title || notificationTitle;
    notificationBody = data?.body || notificationBody;
    notificationIcon = data?.image_url || notificationIcon;
    notificationData = {
      entity_type: data?.entity_type,
      entity_id: data?.entity_id,
    };
  }

  event.waitUntil(
    self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, {
      body: notificationBody,
      icon: notificationIcon,
      data: notificationData,
    })
  );
});

// self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
//  console.log('Push message received.');
//  let notificationTitle = 'New Message Received';
//  const notificationOptions = {
//      body: 'Thanks for sending this push msg.',
//      icon: '/public/Logo.svg',
//      badge: '/public/Logo.svg',
//      data: {
//          url: 'https://web.dev/push-notifications-overview/',
//      },
//  };

//  if (event.data) {
//      const dataText = event.data.text();
//     console.log("event.data",dataText)
//      notificationTitle = 'Received Payload';
//      notificationOptions.body = `Push data: '${dataText}'`;
//  }

//  event.waitUntil(
//      self.registration.showNotification(
//          notificationTitle,
//          notificationOptions,
//      ),
//  );
// });

//  Event listener for notification click
/**
 * Event listener for notification click. When a notification is clicked, this function handles the navigation to the appropriate URL based on the notification data.
 *
 * @param {NotificationEvent} event - The notification click event.
 * @returns {Promise<void>} - A promise that resolves when the navigation is complete.
 */
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', (event) => {
  event.notification.close();
  console.log('clickevent', event);
  let url = `${location.origin}`;
  console.log('surl', url);
  let type = event.notification.data.entity_type;
  let id = event.notification.data.entity_id;

  switch (type) {
    case 'chat':
      url = url + '/chat-room/' + id;
      break;
    case 'trip':
      url = url + '/home?tripId=' + id;
      break;
    case 'request':
      url = url + '/home?tripId=' + id + '&viewRequest=true';
      break;
    default:
      // Handle the default case if needed
      break;
  }

  // Navigate to url
  event.waitUntil(
    self.clients
      .matchAll({ type: 'window', includeUncontrolled: true })
      .then((windowClients) => {
        for (let client of windowClients) {
          // if (client.url === url && 'focus' in client) {
          //   return client.focus();
          // }
          if (client.url.startsWith(location.origin)) {
            // Refresh the window with the new URL
            client.navigate(url);
            return client.focus();
          }
        }
        // If no existing window with the same URL is found, open a new one
        return self.clients.openWindow(url);
      })
  );
});

// OTP route
registerRoute(routeMatcher('/auth/otp'), new NetworkOnly(), 'POST');

// LOGIN route
registerRoute(
  routeMatcher('/auth/login'),
  factory(async (request, handler) => {
    const originalResponse = await handler.fetch(request);

    const data: any = await getBody(originalResponse);

    const a = data?.data?.access_token;
    const r = data?.data?.refresh_token;

    // save access and refresh tokens
    if (typeof a === 'string' && typeof r === 'string') {
      accessToken.update(Promise.resolve(a));
      refreshToken.update(Promise.resolve(r));

      storeOrDeleteRefreshToken();

      // strip tokens from response before sending to client
      return json({
        ...data,
        data: {},
      });
    } else return originalResponse;
  }),
  'POST'
);

/** SWR routes.
 * if `noCache` query param is passed, uses a network-only strategy and stores the result in cache,
 * otherwise uses SWR strategy
 */
// registerRoute(
//   ({ url }) =>
//     cache.user.keys.includes(url.pathname as UserCacheKeys) &&
//     url.origin === import.meta.env.VITE_API_BASE_URL,
//   factory(
//     async (request, handler) => {
//       try {
//         const url = new URL(request.url);
//         const noCacheKey = 'noCache' satisfies keyof User.CacheControlParam;
//         const noCache =
//           'true' ===
//           (url.searchParams.get(
//             noCacheKey
//           ) as User.CacheControlParam['noCache']);

//         url.searchParams.delete(noCacheKey);

//         const req = changeGetRequestURL(url, request, {
//           headers: addAuthHeader(request, await accessToken),
//         });

//         let res: Response;
//         if (noCache) {
//           res = await handler.fetchAndCachePut(req.clone());
//         } else {
//           res = await Promise.any([
//             handler.fetchAndCachePut(req.clone()),
//             handler.cacheMatch(req.clone()).then((res) => {
//               if (!res) throw res;
//               else return res;
//             }),
//           ]).catch((e) => {
//             if (e instanceof AggregateError) return Response.error();
//             else {
//               logger.error('SWR error', e);
//               throw e;
//             }
//           });
//         }

//         if (await isUnauthorized(res))
//           res = await handler.fetchAndCachePut(req);

//         if (url.pathname === cache.user.namedKeys.appConfiguration)
//           setAccessTokenTimeoutDuration(res);

//         return res;
//       } catch (e) {
//         if (e === ErrCodes.LOGIN_REQUIRED) {
//           return json({ message: 'Login required' }, 401);
//         }
//         logger.error('swr error', e);
//       }
//     },
//     { cacheName: cache.user.name }
//   )
// );

/** Matches corider server origin routes */
const defaultApiRouteMatcher: RouteMatchCallback = ({ url }) => {
  return url.origin === import.meta.env.VITE_API_BASE_URL;
};

/** Strategy for all corider apis, checks for 401 status code */
const defaultApiRouteHandler = factory(async (request, handler) => {
  try {
    const req = updateRequest(request, await accessToken);
    const res = await handler.fetch(req.clone());

    if (await isUnauthorized(res)) {
      const req = updateRequest(request, await accessToken);
      return await handler.fetch(req);
    } else {
      return res;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    if (e === ErrCodes.LOGIN_REQUIRED) {
      return json({ message: 'Login required' }, 401);
    }
    logger.error('defult route', e);
  }
});

registerRoute(defaultApiRouteMatcher, defaultApiRouteHandler, 'GET');
registerRoute(defaultApiRouteMatcher, defaultApiRouteHandler, 'POST');
registerRoute(defaultApiRouteMatcher, defaultApiRouteHandler, 'PUT');
registerRoute(defaultApiRouteMatcher, defaultApiRouteHandler, 'DELETE');
registerRoute(defaultApiRouteMatcher, defaultApiRouteHandler, 'PATCH');
registerRoute(defaultApiRouteMatcher, defaultApiRouteHandler, 'HEAD');

/**
 * Service Worker init function
 *
 * Creates IDB database and store if not already created,
 *
 * Fetches refresh token from DB if already existed, else throws.
 *
 * Fetches access token from network if refreh token is found.
 */
function init() {
  isInitCalled = true;
  logger.log('init called');
  const request = self.indexedDB.open(DB.name, DB.version);

  request.onblocked = (e) => {
    logger.error('init blocked');
    (e.target as IDBOpenDBRequest).result?.close();
  };

  request.onupgradeneeded = (e) => {
    const db = request.result;

    db.onerror = (e) => logger.error('Init db error ', e);

    if (db.objectStoreNames.contains(DB.store.name))
      db.deleteObjectStore(DB.store.name);

    db.createObjectStore(DB.store.name, DB.store.options).transaction.commit();
  };

  request.onsuccess = (e) => {
    const db = request.result;
    logger.log('IDB open req success');
    const transaction = db.transaction(DB.store.name, 'readonly');
    const refreshTokenQuery = transaction
      .objectStore(DB.store.name)
      .get(DB.refreshToken.key);

    refreshTokenQuery.onsuccess = async (e) => {
      if (typeof refreshTokenQuery.result === 'string') {
        logger.log('IDB ref success');
        refreshToken.update(Promise.resolve(refreshTokenQuery.result));
        fetchAccessToken();
      } else {
        refreshToken.update(Promise.reject(ErrCodes.LOGIN_REQUIRED));
        accessToken.update(Promise.reject(ErrCodes.LOGIN_REQUIRED));
      }
    };

    refreshTokenQuery.onerror = (e) => {
      logger.error('refresh token query errror', e);
      refreshToken.update(Promise.reject(ErrCodes.LOGIN_REQUIRED));
      accessToken.update(Promise.reject(ErrCodes.LOGIN_REQUIRED));
    };
  };

  request.onerror = (e) => {
    logger.error('init error', e);
  };
}

/**
 * Stores refresh token into IDB.
 *
 * Deletes it if `true` is passed as paramater
 */
function storeOrDeleteRefreshToken(deleteToken?: boolean) {
  const request = self.indexedDB.open(DB.name, DB.version);

  request.onsuccess = async (e: Event) => {
    const transaction = (e.target as IDBOpenDBRequest).result.transaction(
      DB.store.name,
      'readwrite'
    );

    if (deleteToken)
      transaction.objectStore(DB.store.name).delete(DB.refreshToken.key);
    else
      transaction
        .objectStore(DB.store.name)
        .put(await refreshToken, DB.refreshToken.key);
    transaction.commit();
  };

  request.onerror = (e) => {
    logger.error('IDB error', e);
  };
}

/** set a timeout for next access token fetch  */
function setAccessTokenTimer(timeout: number) {
  if (typeof timerId === 'undefined')
    timerId = setTimeout(fetchAccessToken, timeout);
}

/**
 * The only way access token should be used fetched.
 *
 * If the response has status `401`, rejects refresh token and access token, with {@link ErrCodes.LOGIN_REQUIRED} error code.
 *
 * If there was some other cause of failure (e.g. network failure), **resolves** the access token with garbage value
 */
async function fetchAccessToken() {
  logger.log('fetching access token...');

  clearTimeout(timerId);
  timerId = undefined;

  let resolver;
  const _a = new Promise<string>((res) => void (resolver = res));
  accessToken.update(_a, resolver);

  try {
    //using stored push subscription in each refresh request

    const res = await fetch(serverEndpoints.access_token, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        os: platform,
      }),
      headers: new Headers([
        [AUTHORIZATION, `Bearer ${await refreshToken}`],
        [CONTENT_TYPE, APPLICATION_JSON],
      ]),
    });
    if (res.status === 401) {
      // refresh token rejected
      refreshToken.update(Promise.reject(ErrCodes.LOGIN_REQUIRED));

      // Navigate to url
      let url = `${location.origin}/login`;

      self.clients
        .matchAll({ type: 'window', includeUncontrolled: true })
        .then((windowClients) => {
          for (let client of windowClients) {
            // if (client.url === url && 'focus' in client) {
            //   return client.focus();
            // }
            if (client.url.startsWith(location.origin)) {
              // Refresh the window with the new URL
              client.navigate(url);
              return client.focus();
            }
          }
          // If no existing window with the same URL is found, open a new one
          return self.clients.openWindow(url);
        });
      await refreshToken;
    }

    if (!res.ok) {
      throw res;
    }

    const data = await res.json().catch(() => undefined);

    if (typeof data?.access_token === 'string') {
      accessToken.update(Promise.resolve(data.access_token));

      bc.postMessage(data?.access_token);

      setAccessTokenTimer(accessTokenTimeout);
    } else
      throw new Error("invalid server response, couldn't refresh access token");
  } catch (e) {
    // Couldn't fetch access token
    logger.error('acc token', e);
    if (e === ErrCodes.LOGIN_REQUIRED)
      accessToken.update(Promise.reject(ErrCodes.LOGIN_REQUIRED));
    else accessToken.update(Promise.resolve(''));
  }

  return true;
}

/** Sets the timeout duration for access token from the user config api response */
async function setAccessTokenTimeoutDuration(res: Response) {
  const body: any = await getBody(res);
  const tokenTimeout = body?.data?.access_token_expiry_in_seconds;

  if (
    typeof tokenTimeout === 'number' &&
    !isNaN(tokenTimeout) &&
    tokenTimeout !== 0
  ) {
    accessTokenTimeout = tokenTimeout * 1000 - buffer;
  }
}

/** Checks for `401` status code, and fetches the access token if it's not pending.
 *
 * This check must be used in every new RouteHandler/fetch event listener
 */
async function isUnauthorized(res: Response) {
  if (res.status !== 401) return false;

  if (accessToken.state === 'fulfilled') {
    await fetchAccessToken();
  }

  return true;
}

I want to know a couple of things -:

How to implement the toast coming feature on the React application. (I am using a Vite react app)
I want to locally test out this feature. Any help in the testing of this app update feature would be extremely helpful.

I am a newbie with service workers and this is quite confusing for me.
